# Thickbox page not loading(consistently) on page load in IE browsers

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery, thickbox

I am registering the script on my page load event for the thickbox page to open. But some time only the gray background appears and not the thickbox page. Let me know if I am missing anything. Below is the code for registering the thickbox. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
 Dim sb As New StringBuilder()
            sb.AppendLine("<script type=""text/javascript"">")
            sb.AppendLine("jQuery(document).ready(function($)")
            sb.AppendLine("{")
            sb.AppendLine("tb_show(null, ""Thickbox.aspx?TB_iframe=true&height=500&width=500&modal=true"", null)")
            sb.AppendLine("});")
            sb.AppendLine("</script>")
            Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me.GetType(), "RegisterWidgetScript", sb.ToString())
```

I am new to the forum..let me know if any similar thread has the solution?

Thanks
Gabi

Comment: When does only the gray background appear, is it seemingly random or is there a pattern? Also, do you have the code for the tb_show() function too?

Comment: Is there any reason this isn't just in a script block on the aspx side?  The code looks correct, but I would try to put it at the bottom of the page without ASP's help if possible.  Also, try later in the cycle, pre-render or render event.

Comment: Hi Russ,
It happens random and that's also in IE browser.

I don't know how to add the code in the comments..It has content length restrictions. Anyway I'm using 3.1 thickbox version. 
"Thickbox 3.1 - One Box To Rule Them All."

Thanks for you comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
I have fixed this issue.

In IE the imgLoader variable is null since I am calling the tb_show from the asp.net code behind. So I added the below code to check if the object is null and then initialize and assign the image url.

//Check if the image loader is null, this occurs when we call the tb_show method from the code behind
    if ( typeof imgLoader === 'undefined')
            {
                imgLoader = new Image();// preload image
                      imgLoader.src = tb_pathToImage;//Animated loader gif image.
            }
```